# Can't login with Yii

Tags: php, yii, authentication

I developed my site on my local server and had no problem, I then put it on a live server and had no problem, I have since moved it to a VPS but I'm having a strange thing happen in that I can't login any more. The new server has newer software like PHP 5.5 (but my localhost also had that). I'm not really sure where to start with finding the problem.

my config looks like this:

```
'session' =>array(
        'savePath' => '../mySession',
        'sessionName' => 'my_session',
        'cookieParams' => array(
                 'secure' => true,
                ),
    ),
```

I can see my sessions are being saved into the session folder. I am able to change the language of my site which uses a session too. So I'm not entirely sure it is a session problem, or what it is, hence my question.

**Update**

I looked into the action and this is standard Yii code

```
if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            echo 'hello';//$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl); 
    }
```

When I ran this, the page echoed out `Hello` and I could see I was logged in. When I went to click my profile, it then loaded the login page again and showed I was logged out. So It seems to be a session retention issue?

The only thing I can see that is strange is that In my local host I can see my_session and the yii_csrf session. But on my VPS I can see these two and also a PHPSESSION, so I'm wondering if that is causing the conflict, but I don't know.

Comment: You should give us more information about your problem. Try debugging the login process. Does the correct action is entered on the request? Does the authentication process is initialized? Does it succeed? If yes, please share with us the code part that is executed after a successful login?

Comment: Updated my information, I've never had any problems and i've been on two local machines, one running php 5.2, the new running 5.5 and I've never had a problem on my shared host running 5.3 either. So it's a bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've fixed this, despite setting the config file for the `savePath` I ran phpinfo() and it showed my local value as my session save path, but my master value was still the tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code and check if the session component is preloaded (in your configuration file). Maybe the session hasn't started. Finaly make sure your session folder is writeable.

```
 'session'=>array(
                    'timeout'=>3600,
                    'sessionName'=>'my_session',
                    'autoStart'=>true,
                    'class'=>'CHttpSession',
                    'cookieMode'=>'only',
                    'cookieParams' => array(
                        'secure' => true,
                    ),
                ),
```

Comment: I tried with your config and still the same result.